# Story about an invulnerable man

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a really short story, one page at most.

A man invents a portable device that creates an impenetrable force field.
To test it, he sneaks into a nuclear test site, and

> the force field resists the nuclear blast, but the force of the explosion throws the inventor off the planet.

As additional information, something in the wording of the title of the story made me think that it may be part of a series or a chapter of a larger work.

Comment: I remember this too, great story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are, of course referring to Fredric Brown's "[Great Lost Discoveries II - Invulnerability](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61730)", originally collected in his unusually titled 'Nightmares and Geezenstacks' anthology.

It was part of a series of stories subverting three common sci-fi tropes;  invulnerability, invisibility and immortality.

Comment: You misspelled Fredric. By the way, according to the ISFDB page you linked to, the story was first published in the February 1961 issue of [*Gent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gent_(magazine)).

Comment: Actually, the title of that magazine was probably [*The Gent*](http://www.philsp.com/data/images/g/gent_196106.jpg).

Comment: Originally *published* in The Gent. Originally **collected** in the book mentioned

Comment: Yes, I know. Your answer is accurate as far as it goes. I just thought that, if you're going to say where it was first collected, you might as well also say where it was first published. With a shot of the cover of that issue, if you can find one.

Comment: Thanks, that was the one! I'll try to find the other two.